# Installing Steam on Fedora 32 – "Transaction test error"

Tags: fedora, software-installation, steam

I am trying to install Steam on Fedora and having difficulty. 
After executing the following:

```
sudo dnf install -y steam --enablerepo=rpmfusion-nonfree-steam
```

I receive the conflict below:

```
Error: Transaction test error:
file /usr/share/gcc-10/python/libstdcxx/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.opt-1.pyc from install of libstdc++-10.1.1-1.fc32.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-10.0.1-0.11.fc32.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-10/python/libstdcxx/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc from install of libstdc++-10.1.1-1.fc32.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-10.0.1-0.11.fc32.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-10/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.opt-1.pyc from install of libstdc++-10.1.1-1.fc32.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-10.0.1-0.11.fc32.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-10/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc from install of libstdc++-10.1.1-1.fc32.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-10.0.1-0.11.fc32.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-10/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/printers.cpython-38.opt-1.pyc from install of libstdc++-10.1.1-1.fc32.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-10.0.1-0.11.fc32.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-10/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/printers.cpython-38.pyc from install of libstdc++-10.1.1-1.fc32.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-10.0.1-0.11.fc32.x86_64
```

How do I resolve this?
From what I  understand I already have the 32/64-bit package installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular RPM Fusion repositories

```
sudo dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm

sudo dnf install steam
```